# How to add fields from Items Table to Union all to table ItemOtherCode

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Query is supposed to collect **original** items (from `Items` table) and **alternative** items (from `ItemOtherCode` table):

```
SELECT ItemCode,SelPrice1Default, ItemAraName, ItemLatName, 
       ItemNotes, UnitCode, ItemClassCode, ItemGroupCode, 
       ItemSubGroupCode, TaxSet, ExpireDate, ItemType, ItemEquation, 
       ItemDim, NotActive, UnitCode1
  FROM dbo.Items 
 where ItemCode= 10003

 union all

 select OtherCode,BarcodeUnitPrice 
   from ItemOtherCode 
  where ItemCode= 10003
```

But when I make this `union all` of `Items` table and `ItemOtherCode` table, I get an error:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an 
>   equal number of expressions in their target lists.

How to solve this problem?

## DDL

**Items Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ItemAraName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemLatName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemNotes] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [UnitCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemClassCode] [int] NULL,
    [ItemGroupCode] [int] NULL,
    [ItemSubGroupCode] [int] NULL,
    [TaxSet] [float] NOT NULL,
    [ExpireDate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ItemType] [int] NULL,
    [ItemEquation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ItemDim] [int] NULL,
    [NotActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UnitCode1] [int] NULL,
    [BuyPriceDefault] [float] NOT NULL,
    [PriceTypeCode] [int] NULL,
    [SelPrice1Default] [float] NOT NULL,
    [SelPrice2Default] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**ItemOtherCode Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ItemOtherCode](
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [OtherCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [BarcodeUnitPrice] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ItemOtherCode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemCode] ASC,
    [OtherCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Relation between them:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Items i 
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemOtherCode o ON o.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
```

Comment: Do you need one row with all values?

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing a UNION instead of a JOIN. What does your desired result set look like?

Comment: I am not really sure what the question is here. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry for late i need to do union but problem how to get fields from items table . inner join for explaination only

Comment: @techdata you already have the answer

Answer (score 0):

UNION requires same count of fields and same columns name in both queries:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 FIELD4
FROM   TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT OTHER_FIELD1 AS FIELD1, OTHER_FIELD2 AS FIELD2, '' AS FIELD3, 0 AS FIELD4
FROM   TABLE2
```

Answer (score 0):

I surmise that `[OtherCode]` also is supposed to refer to parent `Items` table.

What you have tried:

```
SELECT OtherCode,BarcodeUnitPrice 
FROM ItemOtherCode 
WHERE ItemCode= 10003
```

or the same with `join` as shown in your question for FK explanation:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Items i 
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemOtherCode o ON o.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
WHERE i.ItemCode = 10003
```

Now you have found all the *alternative* items of `10003`. But you need info about those items. Where is info about items stored? In `Items` table of course. So we need to go there once again **but with different ItemCode values**:

```
SELECT io.*
FROM dbo.Items i 
INNER JOIN dbo.ItemOtherCode o ON o.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
INNER JOIN dbo.Items io on io.ItemCode = o.OtherCode --<<<
WHERE i.ItemCode = 10003
```

now we have all fields from `Items` table for all alternative items of `10003`. Can do `union` now.

```
SELECT ItemCode,SelPrice1Default, ItemAraName, ItemLatName, 
       ItemNotes, UnitCode, ItemClassCode, ItemGroupCode, 
       ItemSubGroupCode, TaxSet, ExpireDate, ItemType, ItemEquation, 
       ItemDim, NotActive, UnitCode1
  FROM dbo.Items i
 WHERE i.ItemCode = 10003

 UNION ALL

SELECT ItemCode,SelPrice1Default, ItemAraName, ItemLatName, 
       ItemNotes, UnitCode, ItemClassCode, ItemGroupCode, 
       ItemSubGroupCode, TaxSet, ExpireDate, ItemType, ItemEquation, 
       ItemDim, NotActive, UnitCode1
  FROM dbo.ItemOtherCode o
 INNER JOIN dbo.Items io on io.ItemCode = o.OtherCode
 WHERE o.ItemCode = 10003
```

Don't know what is `BarcodeUnitPrice` supposed to mean so can't say what to do with it.

Comment: If that is the answer that is a poorly written question